# Constructing a point $M$

Tags: geometry

> Let ${\cal C}_1$ and ${\cal C}_2$ be concentric circles, with ${\cal C}_2$ in the interior of  ${\cal C}_1$. From a point $A$ on ${\cal C}_1$ one draws the tangent $AB$ to ${\cal C}_2$ ($B\in {\cal C}_2$). Let $C$ be the second point of intersection of $AB$ and ${\cal C}_1$, and let $D$ be the midpoint of $AB$. A line passing through $A$ intersects ${\cal C}_2$ at $E$ and $F$ in such a way that the perpendicular bisectors of $DE$ and $CF$ intersect at a point $M$ on $AB$. Find a construction for point $M$.

It can be proven that $M$ is the center of the circumcircle of $CFED$, but as for a geometrical construction I am not sure how that helps. The condition that $M$ must lie on $AB$ is also something we need to take consideration in the construction.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is the circumcenter of $CFED$, then it is also the midpoint of $CD$.